# Changing Background Image of div ERROR

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to change the background of a div in a loop between 9 different Images.
I tried to use code I found here on stackoverflow, but something went wrong...
I am new to Java, so I cant find my mistakes.

My CSS where I want to change IMG:

```
.ch-img-1 { 
    background-image: url(Images/round280/1.png) ;
}
```

My code:

```
<body>
<ul class="ch-grid">
<li>
    <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">              
    </div>
</li>
</ul>

<script language="JavaScript">
  var currentBackground = 0;
  var backgrounds = [];
  backgrounds[0] = '/Images/round280/1.png';
  backgrounds[1] = '/Images/round280/2.png';
  backgrounds[2] = '/Images/round280/3.png';
  backgrounds[3] = '/Images/round280/4.png';
  backgrounds[4] = '/Images/round280/5.png';
  backgrounds[5] = '/Images/round280/6.png';
  backgrounds[6] = '/Images/round280/7.png';
  backgrounds[7] = '/Images/round280/8.png';
  backgrounds[8] = '/Images/round280/9.png';

function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

    $('ch-grid.ch-item.ch-img-1').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $('ch-grid.ch-item.ch-img-1').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('ch-grid.ch-item.ch-img-1').fadeIn(100);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);        
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're selecting the div isn't correct. `ch-grid` is a class so you need to use a '.' as a prefix: `.ch-grid` would be the correct way to select the `ul`. Because you want to select the `div` contained within the `ul` you need a space between the parent class (`ch-grid`) and the child classes (`ch-item` and `ch-img-1`). Once the selector is correct, you can reference the object using `$(this)`

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/suf4ueo8/1/)

So your updated JQuery would look like the below:

```
function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if (currentBackground > 8) currentBackground = 0;

    $('.ch-grid .ch-item.ch-img-1').fadeOut(100,function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $this.fadeIn(100);
    });

    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I just put the whole code into a test.js and then link it to my html in the header or can I somehow include the js-code in my html?

Comment: Something works as I can see a fade effect but unfortunately the background is blank after the first change...

Comment: You can do either. It's entirely up to you. I would go for the first option as it will make the content neater and you can update the jquery without needing to re-publish.

Comment: Could it be that your image links are broken? Have you looked at the fiddle example?

Comment: Ok, I did it with a test.js and adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
to my header.

Comment: the image links on Fiddle are for images that can be found online. As my project is local, I just added the local address relative to the hrml and test.js file.
In my software it even shows a litte preview of them when hovering over the links I created...

Comment: Interestingly, if I use the placehold example liks from Fiddle, it works and shows them...

Comment: background-image: url(Images/round280/1.png) is the original source for the still background. This works. And if I use Images/round280/2.png and so on in the jQuery, this does not worrk...

Comment: In the JQuery, your images have a /. Remove the preceding / from the image links in the JQuery and it should work. EDIT: Good to hear.